# Why is the following c# win forms validation method not working?

Tags: c#, winforms, validation

I have a validation method with 5 validation elements to it, 4 of which work as intended but 1 does not, question is why not?

The issue I have is with Validating "CompetitionCourse".  I want the IsValid to be true only if the combobox cbCourseRound1 is not blank.  At the moment this is validating regardless of this combobox being blank or populated.  All other validations are working,

```
private bool Validate(Competition compSetup)
        {
            string CompetitionName = compSetup._CompetitionName;
            int CompetitionFormat = compSetup._CompetitionFormatId;
            string CompetitionGender = cbGenderOfCompetiton.Text;
            string CompetitionMarker = cbMarker.Text;
            string CompetitionCourse = cbCourseRound1.Text;

            if (!CompetitionName.Equals(string.Empty) && !CompetitionGender.Equals("Mixed") && CompetitionFormat.Equals(1) && !CompetitionCourse.Equals(string.Empty) &&
                ((CompetitionGender.Equals("Female") && CompetitionMarker.Equals("Red")) || (!CompetitionGender.Equals("Female") && !CompetitionMarker.Equals("Red"))))
            {
                IsValid = true;
            }
            else
            {
                IsValid = false;
            }
            return IsValid;
        }
```

Comment: Maybe you should try using `!string.IsNullOrEmpty(CompetitionCourse)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

depends on what's in `CompetitionCourse`. You'll have to check that yourself by debugging your code.

You'd be better off making explicitly sure that `CompetitionCourse` contains `null` if the ComboBox text field is blank (because I suspect it contains ""):

```
CompetitionCourse = (string.IsNullOrEmpty(cbCourseRound1.Text)) ? null : cbCourseRound1.Text;
```

Answer (score 0):

> At the moment this is validating regardless of this combobox being
>   blank or populated.

Check the [Items](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.items.aspx) property of the combobox, not the `Text` Property like.

```
cbCourseRound1.Items != null && cbCourseRound1.Items.Count > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, using `.Equals` for strings is very Java. C# has operator overloading which looks a lot nicer:

```
if(CompetitionName!="" && CompetitionGender!="Mixed" ...)
```

As for the test itself, you'll need to set a break point and see what `CompetitionCourse has. My guess is it's not an empty string, but rather has some spaces in it. Try using

```
...!CompetitionCourse.Trim()!=""
```

Comment: I disagree with the first point, it is irrelevant to the question. if i could downvote, i would

Answer (score 0):

Your code is diffficult to read, i'll try to simplify it:

```
private bool Validate(Competition compSetup)
{
    bool isValid = cbGenderOfCompetiton.Text != "Female" && cbMarker.Text == "Red";
    if (!isValid)
    {
        isValid = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(compSetup._CompetitionName);
        if (isValid)
            isValid = compSetup._CompetitionFormatId.Text == "Female";// this is redundant: cbGenderOfCompetiton.Text != "Mixed";
        if (isValid)
            isValid = CompetitionFormat == 1;
        if (isValid)
            isValid = cbCourseRound1.SelectedIndex != -1;
        if (isValid)
            isValid = cbMarker.Text == "Red"; 
    }
    return isValid;
}
```

Note that i've used the `SelectedIndex` instead of `Combobox.Text` because it's less error-prone.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using !Equals, use IsNullOrWhitespace, or IsNullOrEmpty. It works better.

Answer (score 0):

May be you should try to trim the white space around the text box. For example, `txtName.Trim();`